# Trend, Environment and Executors tabs fails to show any data in Allure2 reports

Tags: ruby, cucumber, appium, allure

I have been using Allure1 with Cucumber-Ruby-Appium framework and the reports generated by Allure1 are great. Now Allure has released Allure2 and I have successfully upgraded to this new Allure2 version. Reports are successfully generated in Allure2 new UI.

I see new tabs like **Trend**, **Environment** and **Executors** on the Allure2 dashboard's 'Overview' page. However no data is being reflected in these tabs. Could anyone kindly guide me how can I populate data in these tabs.

I have searched through the allure [docs](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-docs/blob/master/docs/2.0/integration/cucumber.adoc), but nothing has been mentioned on how to achieve this. Any guidance on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To get history data in the report you need to use one of Allure CI plugins (at the moment supported Jenkins, Teamcity and Bamboo) to generate the report.

Comment: I'm using Allure Plugin (ver: 2.18) with allure-commandline (1.5.4) in Jenkins to run my automated suite. However the reports generated in Jenkins is Allure1 and that on machine when run locally I see Allure2 reports with the Trends|Executor tabs empty. Locally I have Allure 2.1.1 configured.